# Can't flip bool value in state of React, it only changes once?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi I'm having some troubles on flipping this damn bool. I am trying to change the value of completed from true to false on a button click. It changes once but then never flips back, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var list = [
  { item: "do the washing", id: 1, completed: true },
  { item: "lose at poker all day", id: 2, completed: true },
  { item: "coded enough?", id: 3, completed: false }
];
```

I have written a handleClick function to flip the bool, but it only seems to flip it once?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: list
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(id) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let available = prevState.data.map((a) => {
        if (a.id === id) {
          a.completed = !a.completed;
          console.log(a.completed);
        }
        return a;
      });
      return { data: available };
    });
  }

  render() {
    let newList = list.map((a) => (
      <ListItem data={a} key={a.id} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
    ));
    return <div>{newList}</div>;
  }
}
```

If it helps my "<ListItem " looks like

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.data.id)}
        />{" "}
        {props.data.completed ? props.data.item : null}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't mutate the previous state directly. See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-browser-b28h9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not iterating through the state, but rather the prop. Change your return statement to have this instead:

```
    let newList = this.state.data.map((a) => (
      <ListItem data={a} key={a.id} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
    ));
```

**Edit**

Sorry, you are right. I would recommend changing your handleClick function. Here is an example of it working correctly:

https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-frog-r51gs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! You mean in my render() function? Didn't catch this, have just quickly changed this but still doesn't seem to toggle the bool. Only changing it once.

Comment: Yeah, turned out, there are two issues. One is the map function and the other is your ```handleClick``` function and how you set a new state. 
I created an example of it working correctly in the sandbox

Answer (score 0):

first, your `handleClick` should not mutate `prevState`. Instead, create a copy and mutate that.

I would recommend your `handleClick` to be like this:

```
handleClick(id){
  this.setState(prevState=>{
    let available = prevState.data.map(a=>{
      // in this case you create a new object but 
      // you overwrite completed value in the new object
      if(a.id === id) return {...a, completed:!a.completed}
      return {...a}
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You need to return the `available` array from the state updater function.